# Frequent OOM Error with WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

**We are getting frequent OOM Error with WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0. The OOM Error is in-fact not due to insufficient heap space but rather is explicitly generated at run time while creating a byte[] of an un-acceptable size viz. INTEGER.MAX value as evident from the heap dumps where we are getting stack trace for OOM Error as given below**

**Can someone suggest what can be possible reason here?**

```
PassThroughMessageProcessor-301" prio=5 tid=2866 RUNNABLE
at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:48)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:239)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil$ReadOnlyBIS#1
   local variable: byte[]#859071
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil$ReadOnlyBIS#1
   local variable: byte[]#680420
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil$ReadOnlyBIS#1
   local variable: byte[]#680420
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil$ReadOnlyBIS#1
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe$ByteBufferOutputStream#1
   local variable: byte[]#680420
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:1168)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil$ReadOnlyBIS#1
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext#50
at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:378)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil$ReadOnlyBIS#1
at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:70)
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext#50
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.sendRequestContent(PassThroughHttpSender.java:414)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender#1
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe#23
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:277)
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext#50
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext#50
   local variable: com.dynatrace.agent.TraceTag#868
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient#1
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext#50
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext#51
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:656)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:86)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:573)
at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:409)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint#97
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.send(HTTPEndpoint.java:100)
at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:56)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:123)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorLog#1
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator#187
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorLog#2
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:205)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator#403
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorLog#3
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator#403
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorLog#4
at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:331)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource#186
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:447)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler#1
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
   local variable: java.util.ArrayList#139741
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:73)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:99)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver#1
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext#5
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext#52
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker#18
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:426)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker#18
   local variable: com.dynatrace.agent.TraceTag#868
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181)
   local variable: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker#18
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1#6
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.Axis2ThreadPoolExecutor#1
   local variable: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#908
   local variable: java.lang.Thread#981
   local variable: org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1#6
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

BufferedInputStream.java line #239 infact is

```
byte[] nbuf = new byte[nsz];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to find a exact root case with the given thread stack trace. This may be the thread complaining about the OOM but who is not utilizing the heap memory.
If the server is experiencing an OOM you may find the self generated heap dump as /repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof file. This dump needs to be investigated to find a possible memory leak or components that are consuming more heap memory which might lead to an OOM issue.